# Google Apps Script deleteCompanyField()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to delete all companies/titles in my Google Contacts. The following code deletes everything but one. Can someone help?

```
for (var i = 0; i < noComps; i++) {
 var cComp = contacts.getCompanies()[i];
 var r = cComp.deleteCompanyField();
}
```

My `contacts` variable & `noComps` has been predefined, just not outlined here.

Essentially what I'm looking to do is make a direct update in Google Sheets and have it sync up to Google Contacts. I have the `onEdit(e)` function established.

Comment: The `noComps` variable should be assigned a number with `noComps = contacts.length;`

Comment: @SandyGood
thanks for responding. I do have it set.
<br/>
`var noComps = contacts.getCompanies().length;<br/>
 `           `for(var i = 0; i < noComps; i++){<br/>
 `             var cComp = contacts.getCompanies()[i];<br/>
 `             ui.alert('Company Name: ' + cComp.getCompanyName() + ' Title: ' + cComp.getJobTitle());<br/>
 `             var r = cComp.deleteCompanyField();<br/>
 `             //ui.alert('Deletion result: ' + r);<br/>
 `           }<br/>
 `           return;<br/>

Sorry I have no clue how to format for line of code here..

Comment: @Will extensive code doesn't belong in comments so there is no support for richly formatting it.

Comment: Use back-ticks for formatting code in comments.  [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to be structured like the following:

```
function test() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName('John Doe');

  var companies,i,j,L,nmbrOfCompanies,thisCompany;

  L = contacts.length;

  for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    companies = contacts[i].getCompanies();

    nmbrOfCompanies = companies.length;

    for (j = 0; j < nmbrOfCompanies; j++) {
      thisCompany = companies[j];
      //Logger.log('thisCompany: ' + thisCompany);
      thisCompany.deleteCompanyField();
    }
  }

}
```

There can be multiple companies for each contact.  So, you need a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple mutation + iteration issue: within your loop over the contact's companies, you request their companies. However, you then delete an entry, so the next call will skip the company that would have been next. Instead, you should iterate backwards, and avoid reacquiring the iterated object within the loop:

```
var comps = contact.getCompanies();
var i = comps.length;
while (i > 0) {
  var comp = comps[--i];
  ...
  comp.deleteCompanyField();
}
```

An alternative is to use a `forEach` array function:

```
contact.getCompanies().forEach(function (comp, i, allTheirCompanies) {
  ...
  comp.deleteCompanyField();
});
```